# Is there a way to do pre-compression with on-the-fly-uncompression in nginx?

Tags: performance, gzip, nginx

It's easy to use the pre-compression module to look for a pre-compressed .gz version of a page and serve it to browsers that accept gzip to avoid the overhead of on-the-fly compression, but what I would like to do is eliminate the uncompressed version from disk and store only the compressed version, which would obviously be served the same way, but then if a user-agent that does not support gzip requests the page I would like for nginx to uncompress is on the fly before transmitting it.

Has anyone done this or are there other high performance web servers that provide this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to send static pre-compressed gzipped files on Nginx is by using the http_gzip_static_module.
More specifically in the configuration you will want:

> gzip_static always;

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html

To be able to serve up the unzipped version of the file i.e. you only have the .gz file on your server to save on IO, you will want to use the http_gunzip_module. In your config it looks like this:

> gunzip on;

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html

You may also be interested in the links at the bottom of the gunzip_module page.

P.S. When pre-compressing files I'd suggest using Google's Zopfli compression algorithm, it will increase the build time (not the decompression time), but decrease the file size by about 5%.
https://code.google.com/p/zopfli/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a [fall-back](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#Named_Locations) [upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule) server to decompress the file, eg:

```
gzip_static on;
...
upstream decompresser {
    server localhost:8080; // script which will decompress the file
}

location / {
    try_files $uri @decompress;
}

location @decompress {
    proxy_pass http://decompresser;
}
```

Another option would be to use the [embedded perl module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxEmbeddedPerlModule) as the fall-back rather than the upstream, however this can cause nginx to block and if the operation lasts a while could decrease performance.

With the upstream model you may be able to take advantage of nginx's [XSendfile](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile) module by using the system's default `gzip` program to decompress to a file in the /tmp directory. This could save on decompression overhead per-request by allowing the file to hang around for a short while.